# Python Pandas giving wrong number of columns on df.loc

Tags: python, pandas, database

[image]

So I tried printing my quantity column after data cleanup, and its bugged, it showed 202634 rows even if it is 202129 rows long. I tried saving the data into excel and checking manually, the real number of rows is 202129, so why does pandas show 202634? The data before cleaning was 203000+ rows. Anyone knows why is this? How can this be fixed?

Comment: The image you show clearly indicates `202129` rows, you're confusing the indices with the number of rows. Obviously you have missing indices. You might want to `reset_index(drop=True)`

Comment: Oh so indices stay the same, even the rows before it doesn't exist anymore? I checked row 202634 is value 4 in original dataset

Comment: The numbers on the left indicate the line index. This means that some indexes, and, accordingly, rows, are not in your dataframe now, you deleted them when you cleaned the data.

Comment: You can bring the index into line with the number of rows using `df.reset_index(inplace = True)`

Comment: Yes, when you delete rows the indexes stay the same. To update your indexes, if you want, use the function that mozway gave you above.

Answer (score 0):

This is because some of the samples have been deleted, but the index number of the next sample has not been replaced. For this, it is enough to reset the index numbers as follows:

`df = df.reset_index(drop = True)`